# How do I call an elisp function which may or may not be defined?

Tags: elisp

I've tried using functionp and fboundp, and am wondering what the difference is and how they can be used to maybe-call a function.

`(functionp OBJECT)` - Non-nil if OBJECT is a function.

`(fboundp SYMBOL)` - Return t if SYMBOL's function definition is not void.

For example, I'm trying to do:

```
(if (python-shell-get-buffer)
    .... 
    ....
```

But python-shell-get-buffer doesn't get defined until run-python has been run.
If I just try to call it, before its defined, I get:

> Symbol's function definition is void: python-shell-get-buffer

I've tried using

```
(if (and (fboundp python-shell-get-buffer) (python-shell-get-buffer))
```

and

```
(if (and (functionp python-shell-get-buffer) (python-shell-get-buffer))
```

but they also result in

> Symbol's value as variable is void: python-shell-get-buffer

How do I call a function which may or may not be defined ?

Comment: `(fboundp SYMBOL)` - supply a SYMBOL, such as `(fboundp 'python-shell-get-buffer)`. Use `functionp` when wishing to test the resulting *type* of object, once the expression is evaluated.

Comment: That's it. I didn't quote the symbol.

Comment: `(if (and (fboundp 'python-shell-get-buffer) (python-shell-get-buffer))`   seems to do what I want without choking